# Why is my ArrayList empty after adding new objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

Why is this ArrayList empty when I print it out?

```
ArrayList<InterviewQuestion> interviewQuestionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <interviewQuestionArrayList.size(); i++) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
}

System.out.println(interviewQuestionArrayList);
```

Comment: can we see how do you print it`

Comment: Because the loop runs zero times - you iterate over the indices of an empty list.

Comment: I'm expecting to see an ArrayList of object references.

Comment: Check... `interviewQuestionArrayList.size()` for the size? Guess what? It's empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created arraylist but before adding you are trying to looping through it.. size will be zero initially..

If you know how many interviewQuestions are there then you can loop with that number.

ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i <numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
}
```

numberOfQuestions should be predifined..

Initially if you dont know how many times you want to add then you can use while loop. But you should exit from while based on some condition

like,

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
    if(condition) flag = false;
} //something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see, your List is empty when you enter the loop.
Thus its size() will return 0 and the loop will not add any elements.

your code basically does

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you create an empty list -> this means the size is currently 0

```
 ArrayList<InterviewQuestion> interviewQuestionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The following loop is never executed because i (now 0) is never < size (now 0)
This means there are no Objects added to your list

```
for (int i = 0; i <interviewQuestionArrayList.size(); i++) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
}
```

Try using `i<10` as the condition in the for loop to add 10 elements to the list

Answer (score 0):

if this 2 staments are followed by each other, then your list is never populated:

```
ArrayList<InterviewQuestion> interviewQuestionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <interviewQuestionArrayList.size(); i++) {
    interviewQuestionArrayList.add(new InterviewQuestion());
}
```

ergo, you have an empty list to print

```
System.out.println(interviewQuestionArrayList);
```

you can play with some dummyData that you add when declaring the list

Comment: I see. But I want to populate it dynamically. Setting the initial capacity to some arbitrary integer doesn't work as well.

Comment: @santafebound Of course not. Capacity is not the same as size.

Comment: @santafebound initial capacity doesn't change the *size* of the `ArrayList`, only the size of its internal `array`.

Comment: @santafebound you condition needs to be the number of items you want to add. Eg. for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){...} would iterate 5 times and thus add 5 items.